# @internal doesn't seem to be working

Tags: phpdoc

```
<?php
/**
 * test script - short description
 *
 * long description
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * {@internal this is a test of a multi line internal note
 * another test}}}
 */
class test {}
```

The example at http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.internal.pkg.html has one opening { and three closing }'s. When I try that and then try to generate the documentation with `phpdoc -d . -t output` I get this:

[image]

I don't know what I should be seeing but this looks like it has not been parsed / has been ignored.

When I try it with a single closing } I get the same unparsed / ignored look.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax that uses braces is only to embed the tag into a larger description.  Since your usage is just as a standalone tag, you don't need any of the braces.